# Firebase Google sign-in not opening authentication after clicking continue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing firebase google login in Swift on a view controller. After implementing I am getting the permission prompt alert, but once click on continue in alert nothing happened just closed the alert view. Same thing happing for Facebook login too. Any idea?

[image]

Thanks in advance

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    // ...
    if let error = error {
        // ...
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    // ...
}
@IBAction func signInClick(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

After doing a bit more debugging I have found that after tapping on continue, it is trying to call SFSafariViewController, But SafariViewController not been showing.

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would be good if you post also your code for the google or Facebook login delegate, to check how you are handling this.

Comment: @RenanSilveira, I have updated code and logs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the problem. The application is holding two UIWindow, and Google/Facebook sign-in webview is adding to a UIWindow which is not been visible.

[image]

I have resolved the issue, 

Thanks!
Ramesh